# Js on click triggers a php update, it also triggers on load

Tags: javascript, php

this works for me on delete button, but this works when I go to this page also, on load of page it triggers status update i dont want that to change unless i click delete

Is it because it is php inside js or what?

```js
var deleted_question = 0;
$(document).on("click", "button[id=removequestion]", function(data) {
  var total_question_nr = <?php echo count($questions);?>;
  var test_status = <?php echo $test->status; ?>;

  if (test_status == 1) {
    if ((total_question_nr - deleted_question) == 1) {
      var result = confirm("@lang('general.if_questions_zero_test')");
      console.log(total_question_nr - deleted_question);
      if ((total_question_nr - deleted_question) == 0) {
        var status = <?php echo $test->update(['status' => 0]); ?>;
      }
    } else {
      var result = confirm("@lang('general.are_you_sure_want_to_delete_question')?");
    }
  } else {
    var result = confirm("@lang('general.are_you_sure_want_to_delete_question')?");
  }

  if (result) {
    var questionid = $(this).val();

    $.ajax({
      method: "POST",
      url: "{{ url('/questions/delete-question') }}",
      data: {
        _token: "{{ csrf_token() }}",
        question_id: questionid,
      },
      success: function(response) {
        $("button[id=removequestion][value=" + questionid + "]").parent().parent().fadeOut('slow');
        deleted_question++;
        if ((total_question_nr - deleted_question) == 0) {
          $('#publish-col').find('a').each(function() {
            $(this).addClass("disabled");
          });
        }
      },
      error: function() {
        console.log("error");
      }
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: This statement is executed always: `<?php echo $test->update(['status' => 0]); ?>` - just by loading the page

Comment: What do you mean exactly with `it triggers status update`? For example this piece of php will be executed regardless - and before - of anything javascript related: `<?php echo $test->update(['status' => 0]); ?>`.

Comment: how can I update on different way ths status

Comment: in `/questions/delete-question` and show the result in the success

Comment: All the PHP codes will work on load time and will generate the complete JS script.